# need help decipher a java-based time format at a http request

Tags: java, javascript, timestamp

I have a problem with a http request to a page. the transmitted data from my filled out form on the website, I can not decrypt.
The time and date are encoded in 7 signs. Here are uppercase, lowercase letters, numbers and a few special characters like eg underlined.

The string-is continuous, when I get a minute changeable to change the last 3 characters. but for example, the number 2 has not deposited the same letter etc.

I'm sorry that I have no example. I'm just at home and the server on which I want to access is on my work.

many greetings from Germany and advance many thanks for the help!

Here are the examples.

URK4AgA is 19.02.2014 at 17:00
URAk1AA is 17.02.2014 at 17:00
URKOzyA is 19.02.2014 at 14:00
UGDVrYA is 04.10.2013 at 14:00

Sorry for my bad English....

Comment: An example would be extremely helpful. Are you trying to decode the string server-side or client-side?

Comment: an example I put in, as soon as I am at work. I would decrypt it client-side, because I know not at all how to do it differently

Comment: Hi, URK4AgA is 19.02.2014 at 17:00; URAk1AA is 17.02.2014 at 17:00;

Comment: Hi, URK4AgA is 19.02.2014 at 17:00; URAk1AA is 17.02.2014 at 17:00; URKOzyA is 19.02.2014 at 14:00; UGDVrYA is 04.10.2012 at 14:00.

Comment: I've sussed it out. I'll post an answer when the question is reopened.

Comment: How I can reopen the question

Comment: I dunno. I flagged it. Just gotta wait for the lazy mods or the stupid queue system.  Edit: Or post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a count in base 64 of millisecond units since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch). What makes it a bit more confusing is that (1) the times in your examples are one hour offset from that, which I assume is Germany time; (2) one of them <strike>has</strike> had the wrong year (2012 should be 2013); (3) one of them also has DST. Apart from that, it does work out.

The most common base 64 alphabet uses `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `+` and `/`. However, you said some of the timestamps contain underscores, so I assume it is the variant base 64 alphabet that uses `-` and `_` for the last two characters. There are other variations though, so it's impossible to be certain of the alphabet without more examples.

You haven't said which language you're actually using, but here are Java methods for encoding and decoding those timestamps, which convert them to and from Java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. (You can easily change that to use plain integer timestamps if wanted.)

```java
private static final String timestampAlphabet =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

public static String encodeTimestamp(Date date) {
    long t = date.getTime();
    StringBuilder timestamp = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        timestamp.append(timestampAlphabet.charAt((int)(t % 64)));
    } while ((t /= 64) != 0);
    return timestamp.reverse().toString();
}

public static Date decodeTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    long t = 0;
    for (char c : timestamp.toCharArray()) {
        t = t * 64 + timestampAlphabet.indexOf(c);
    }
    return new Date(t);
}
```

Here are the same functions in JavaScript, which convert to/from JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects:

```javascript
var timestampAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

function encodeTimestamp(date) {
    var t = date.getTime();
    var timestamp = "";
    do {
        timestamp = timestampAlphabet[t % 64] + timestamp;
    } while (t = Math.floor(t / 64));
    return timestamp;
}

function decodeTimestamp(timestamp) {
    var t = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
        t = t * 64 + timestampAlphabet.indexOf(timestamp.charAt(i));
    }
    return new Date(t);
}
```

Edit: Here's VBA. Never bother me again.

```vb
Private Const TimestampAlphabet As String = _
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"

Public Static Function EncodeTimestamp(ByVal d As Date) As String
    Dim t As Variant
    t = (CDec(d) - 25569) * 86400000
    Do
        EncodeTimestamp = Mid(TimestampAlphabet, 1 + t - (64 * Fix(t / 64)), 1) + EncodeTimestamp
        t = Fix(t / 64)
    Loop While t > 0
End Function

Public Static Function DecodeTimestamp(ByVal timestamp As String) As Date
    Dim t As Variant, i As Integer
    t = CDec(0)
    For i = 1 To Len(timestamp)
        t = t * 64 + InStr(TimestampAlphabet, Mid(timestamp, i, 1)) - 1
    Next
    DecodeTimestamp = CDate(CDbl((t / 86400000) + 25569))
End Function
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I again looked at the source code of the page. Can it be that the following lines are the right ones? 


Furthermore, I use VBA in excel as a programming language.

Comment: "if(_2=="last()")return[_1.last()];var _4=_2.match(/^([a-zA-Z_0-9:\-\.\(\)]*)\s*(<|>|!=|=|<=|>=|)\s*(.*)$/),_5,_6,_7;if(_4==null){if(!_2.match(/^[a-zA-Z_0-9:\-\.]*$/)){this.logWarn("couldn't parse predicate expression: "+_2);return null}
_5=_2}else{_5=_4[1],_6=_4[2],_7=_4[3]}
if(_6=="=")_6="==";if(_7=="true()")_7=true;else if(_7=="false()")_7=false;if(_5=="position()")_5="position";var _8=new Function("item,position","return "+(_5!="position"?"item.":"")+_5+(_6?_6+_7:""));var _9=[];for(var i=0;i<_1.length;i++){if(_8(_1[i],i+1))_9.add(_1[i])}
return _9}

Comment: @user3326698 So basically, you didn't include the necessary examples to make the question answerable in any form, so it got closed, and I had to spend hours waiting around to answer it, trying to flag down mods and beg in the chat for someone to come and reopen it, or waiting for you to post it again. When you did include minimal examples, you messed up one of the dates. Now it turns out that neither of the programming languages you tagged has anything to do with any of it and neither of which you even know. JavaScript is not Java. And no, those lines have nothing to do with timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. i suppose it an will be be make it better at next time. Your answer help me so many thanks for this.